# Getting timestamp of last insert in mysql along with primary key in a single query?

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I tried searching for the solution to this problem but am still stuck. Seems rather simple (or maybe it's my ignorance :)

I already fetch the 'auto incremented' primary key after inserting. My question is can I retrieve the timestamp of the last insert WITHOUT sending a second query of

```
SELECT m.timestamp from My_Table m where id = 123; //i.e., 123 is the id of the row that was just created
```

It seems wasteful to go back and forth but is that really the way to do it?

I'm using Spring's JDBCTemplate to query the MySQL DB.

Comment: It seems the way to do it is to fire two queries in a batch and return an array with the responses. Will post an answer once I code it up :)

Answer (score 1):

What is important is getting the last inserted id. Check this 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Sometimes, there is no easy way.